# Use the same file in more than one solution

Tags: vb.net

Just wondering whether it is possible to used a single form into more than 1 solutions?

I have frmbookstock.vb in solution A and i need to use frmbookstock.vb in solution B as well. So every time i change the content of the frmbookstock.vb, both of the solution will received the update as well.

I have tried to import it to another solutions, but it will create a new file under the new solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

In Visual Studio go to the folder that you want to add the existing item to.

1. Right click and Go to "*Add*".
2. Select "*Existing Item*".
3. Select your file.
4. **IMPORTANT STEP**: Select the little dropdown arrow ***next*** to the "Add" button.
5. Select "***Add as Link***" instead.

This will place a ***link to the original file in the source folder***.

So now you have two Visual Studio items in different projects that point to the same, real, file on your hard drive.